# Extracting text from a web page with Nutch

Tags: java, web-scraping, nutch

I'm brand new to Nutch, so please bear with me on this one.

My goal is to simply extract some content from a web page and be able to retrieve the resultant information. For example, let's say I've crawled some pages on an e-commerce site and intend to store product information (i.e., name, category, price, etc).

To reiterate, suppose my seed.txt file contains www.site.com and I initialize a crawl. Assume my HtmlParseFilters are set up to correctly parse product information from www.site.com, and that this crawl will parse both www.site.com and www.site.com/link. If www.site.com contains product A with ID 1 and www.site.com/link contains product B with ID 2, I'm expecting I'll be able to use some sort of predefined utility to give me those results alone:

`A 1`

B 2

At the moment, I'm finding myself modifying org.apache.nutch.segment.SegmentReader and the toString() methods of org.apache.nutch.parse.ParseResult AND org.apache.nutch.metadata.MetaData to isolate my extracted results, which makes me feel like I'm missing something... I don't want to see the outlinks, recno, URL, parse metadata, Playback or any other crawl metadata; I just want the results of my HTML filtration, as described above.

In short, I'm really trying to understand how to use nutch to scrape a group of sites and give me ONLY what I have extracted.

Don't hesitate to let me know if you need any clarification.

Comment: Which version of Nutch, you are using?